# How to edit datetime value in datagridview without datetimepicker?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, datagridview, datetimepicker

I have a datetime column in datagridview and I display it in custom format: dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss

I want to edit datetime value, so I tried adding a datetimepicker control and it works if the values are properly choosed. (yet I don't feel it is efficient).

Sometimes the invalid values are accepted and dgv_dataerror event occurs infinitely without letting me to change the value.

For example, when I keeping moving from one cell to another using keyboard arrow keys, accidentally if I press space bar, the cell value becomes empty and dataerror event occurs infinitely.

Is there any alternative solution to achieve this without datetimepicker control for changing the datetime value?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

It creates a type of DataGridViewColumn with the DateTime picker...

Edit: How to add this custom column dynamically:

```
        dgvMain.DataSource = bulkImportTable;
        CalendarColumn col = new CalendarColumn();
        col.Name = "DeployDate";
        dgvMain.Columns.Remove("DeployDate");
        dgvMain.Columns.Add(col);

        col.DataPropertyName = col.Name;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvMain.Rows)
        {
            row.Cells[dgvMain.Columns.Count - 1].Value = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        }
```

In this code I use the ToShortDateString(), but you can use your own custom method here. Be sure to also change this custom code in the customized CalendarColumn...
THe advatage of using ShortDateString and LongDateString, is that this changes dynamically when the client has a different regional setting...

Comment: This is what i was expecting. But, here the column is added dynamically. How do I achieve this behaviour if the datagridview is populated from datatable?

Comment: How do I apply this calender cell template to the datetime column in datagridview ?
I tried setting the calender cell template for the datetime column, it works only after sorting any column in datagridview. dgv.Invalidate() is not doing the job.

Comment: By removing and adding the Column...Maybe you can post your code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34550178/c-custom-celltemplate-is-not-invalidating-in-datagridview 

Check this link, I have posted a question separately. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Given the limitations of Visual Studio 2005, creating a custom cell type for DataGridView with a MaskedTextBox may involve more complex steps. If you're using Visual Studio 2005 and encountering this issue, you might consider using a different approach, such as validating the input after it's entered or using a separate form for entering the time in the desired format.

If you're open to using a newer version of Visual Studio, such as Visual Studio 2015 or later, you can take advantage of more advanced DataGridView features and third-party libraries that provide built-in support for masked input.
class Program
{
static bool ValidateTimeFormat(string input)
{
// Regular expression pattern to match the time format (hh:mm:ss)
string pattern = @"^(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$";

```
    // Create a Regex object with the pattern
    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

    // Use the IsMatch method to check if the input matches the pattern
    return regex.IsMatch(input);
}

static void Main()
{
    // Example usage
    string timeInput = "12:34:56";
    if (ValidateTimeFormat(timeInput))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The input represents a valid time format.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The input does not represent a valid time format.");
    }
}
```

}