# C#: custom celltemplate is not invalidating in datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datetimepicker, celltemplate

I am displaying some data in datagridview whose datasource is a datatable.

For DateTime column, I want to use datetimepicker control to edit the value.
So I tried the following code found in this link.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80

After assigning the custom cell template to the DateTime column, datagridview is not invalidating immediately.

Here is the code I tried

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;

CalendarCell cell = new CalendarCell();
this.dataGridView1.Columns["DATE"].CellTemplate = cell;
this.dataGridView1.Invalidate();
```

When I sort any column in datagridview. Then the custom template works.

I tried this also, still it is not working.

```
dataGridView1.InvalidateColumn(2);
```

How do I tell datagridview to invalidate immediately so that custom template works properly without the need of sorting the column?